# try to have a single row view from several tables in group by in view

Tags: sql

The is one to many relation between first column in first table to first columns for the next two tables
When I make a view with union all between the three tables I can’t have a one row result because the value fields with the yellow color are group by.
The best result I get is to select first() in the yellow column of first table and 0 in the others but I see this as source of error and the result not a single row.

What I can do in the view to have a single row result like this

[a pictures for the three table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vis1depsag4zt66/RCH.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: can you please post sample data, tables structure and expected results. SqlFiddle.com - if you provide sample here, you will get answer quicker.

Comment: Also tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i attached a sample pdf file for the problem